# Computed column with alias is not mapping into TypeORM Entity

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get data from a table of a **MySQL** database using **TypeORM** in my **Express.js** project.

I'm using `QueryBuilder` to get data.

**My implementation:**

```
const result = await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("post")
                     .skip((request.PageNo - 1) * request.PageSize)
                     .take(request.PageSize)
                     .select([
                        "post.Id",
                        "post.Title",
                        "SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150) AS post_Content",
                        "post.ReadTime",
                        "post.CreatedDate"
                     ])
                    .getRawAndEntities();
```

**Result:**

```
{
  raw: [
    TextRow {
      post_Id: '457457',
      post_CreatedDate: 2021-03-17T18:00:00.000Z,
      post_Title: 'This is a random title',
      post_ReadTime: 3,
      post_Content: "If you're looking for random paragraphs, you've come to the right place. When a random word or a random sentence isn't quite enough, the next logical "
    }
  ],
  entities: [
    Post {
      CreatedBy: '',
      CreatedDate: 2021-03-17T18:00:00.000Z,
      Content: '',
      Title: 'This is a random title',
      ReadTime: 3,
      IsFeatured: false,
      Id: '457457'
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expectation:**
As you can see, I need a substring of the `Content` column. I've added alias as TypeORM convention, I think. But the column is not being mapped to the property.

I've also got the raw data, where you can see the substring of the column with alias is working.

**Alternates I've tried:**

- `"SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150)"`
- `"SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150) AS Content"`
- `"SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150) AS post.Content"`
- "SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150) AS `post.Content`"

But not a single one maps the `Content` column to the `Content` property of the `Post` entity.

**Note:** The `Content` column is only mapped when I'm not using any alias.

**For trace:**
Generated Raw SQLs:

1. When not using alias

   SELECT `post`.`Id` AS `post_Id`, `post`.`CreatedDate` AS `post_CreatedDate`, `post`.`Title` AS `post_Title`, `post`.`Content` AS `post_Content`, `post`.`ReadTime` AS `post_ReadTime` FROM `Posts` `post`  LIMIT 10
2. When using alias

   SELECT `post`.`Id` AS `post_Id`, `post`.`CreatedDate` AS `post_CreatedDate`, `post`.`Title` AS `post_Title`, `post`.`ReadTime` AS `post_ReadTime`, SUBSTRING(`post`.`Content`, 1, 150) AS `post_Content` FROM `Posts`
   `post`  LIMIT 10

**Please help!!!**

**Edit (Working Solution):**

```
const result = await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("post")
                     .skip((request.PageNo - 1) * request.PageSize)
                     .take(request.PageSize)
                     .select([
                        "post.Id",
                        "post.Title",
                        "post.Content",
                        "SUBSTRING(post.Content, 1, 150) AS post_Content",
                        "post.ReadTime",
                        "post.CreatedDate"
                     ])
                    .getMany();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many people over many years have asked the same question.

Examples:

- [Issue 296](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/296) Select additional computed columns (still open)
- [Issue 1822](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822) Add custom select and map to property of entity (closed as duplicate)
- [Issue 7008](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7008) Unable to addSelect with computed result (still open)
- [PR 4703](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/4703) Added support for selecting computed columns (still open)
- [PR 6855](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/6855) Add select and map function to MySQL Driver (still open)

[Comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822#issuecomment-376069476) dated 2018-03-26 by the typeorm author on Issue 1822 : "Official solution named addSelectAndMap will come into QueryBuilder in 0.3.0" (There is no sign of this yet).

On issue #1822 there is a comment with a [workaround](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822#issuecomment-573492291).

First, you have to add `{ select: false }` to the computed column in your entity

```
@Column({ select: false } )
Content: string;
```

Then use `addSelect(selection, alias)` for the computed column [(addSelect with alias overload)](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/3d876c61fafc815e429c68f4f4e1ab79e47c7b9c/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts#L137)

```
addSelect("SUBSTRING(post.Content,1,3)", "post_Content")
```

Comment: `addSelect(selection, alias)` is not available when array is passed into select extension.
`@Column({ select: false } )` did the trick for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, the array doesn't work with alias. I'm glad the workaround worked for you in the end. I'm learning the tricks by answering questions like this.

Comment: But, I've found an issue with my workaround, that `@Column({ select: false } )` directly doesn't work. You can see at my working solution I've selected the Content column two times, one time without an alias and the other with an alias. So, the SQL selects the column two times and magically maps the one with the alias. But without the column without an alias, it doesn't map.

Comment: Did you try: .select([columns excluding calculated]).addSelect("calculated column", "Alias") ?

Comment: I tested ".select().addSelect(), and found like you, it doesn't work! It seems ".select()"  in the query breaks it. You can use .addSelect with array, that seems work. Just make sure you remove any ".select".

Comment: `addSelect()` selects all the columns with the calculated column. So, if I want to fetch only one calculated column from the table, it will provide me all the columns with the calculated one. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Yes it's frustrating. All I can suggest if you don't want all the columns, is put {select: false } on all the columns of your entity, and when you need them you have to add them using "addSelect".

Comment: That's the perfect solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: A convoluted workaround rather than the perfect solution, but I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: This solution is so helpful thanks a lot!